# C++ vector with unlimited dimensions

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-construction, interpreter, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm making a parse tree for an interpreter. Here's what the code for a node in my tree looks like:

```
struct rtok {
    std::string type;
    std::string val;
};

struct rnode  {
    rtok tok;
    vector<rnode> child;
} node;

vector<rnode> ptree;
```

The tree works until I try to use "push_back()" on "node.child" i.e. `node.child[0].push_back();`

"rtok" is just a custom structure I made to store tokens in, I only included it to make the example more complete.

I think the reason why `node.child[0].push_back();` won't work is because the base vector (`ptree`) that holds the parse tree is only 1 dimensional. So my question is, is there a way to make C++ dynamically add new dimensions to the `ptree` vector as needed?

**--EDIT--**

I left out the function for adding new nodes to the vectors:

```
void add_term(rtok tok) {
    rnode n;
    n.tok = tok;
    ptree.back().child.push_back(n);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node.child[0]` doesn't exist until you create it. After `node` is created, `node.child` will be an empty vector, so accessing the first (via `[0]`) is undefined.

To get this to work, give `child` an initial size or add elements to it, and then use them:

```
node.child.push_back(rnode());
node.child[0].push_back(...);
```

Comment: That's what I thought first, but I have a function that adds new terms into the vector and I run that first, so there should be 1 item in the node.child vector already. I've update my question with the function.

Answer (score 0):

My bad! I was trying to insert items into the vector without referencing the child element of my `node` struct.

i.e. I was doing this:

```
ptree.back().child[0].push_back(n);
```

When I should've done this:

```
ptree.back().child[0].child.push_back(n);
```

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers.